# jQuery positioning in internet explorer

Tags: jquery, css

I need to put the video right in the middle (horizontaly) of the page, in chrome and firefox it works perfect, but in internet explorer (IE11) it doesnt (it starts a bit too much to the left).

When I resize my browser, it works fine, even though the code is just copy pasted from above.

Can anyone help me?

Link with example: http://cardio.abcsucces.be/pages/comprendre1.html

Code:

```js
jQuery

$(document).ready(function() {
  var height = $(window).height();
  var width = $(window).width();
  var logoh = height / 6;
  var font = height / 18;
  var font1 = font / 3;
  var font2 = font / 2;
  var containerw = width * 0.7;
  var containerh = height * 0.8;
  var res1 = 1938 / 1252;
  var res2 = containerw / containerh;
  var videoh = containerh * 0.87;
  var imgh = containerh * 0.129;
  var radius = height / 20;
  $("h1").css("font-size", font + "px");
  $("#title").css("top", font1 + "px");
  $("#menu p").css("font-size", font2 + "px");
  $("#hand1, #hand2").css("height", logoh + "px");
  $("#title, #hand1, #hand2").css("margin-top", font1 + "px");
  $("#container").css("max-width", containerw + "px");
  $("#container").css("max-height", containerh + "px");
  $("video").css("border-radius", radius + "px");
  if (res1 > res2) {
    $("#container video").css("width", containerw + "px");
    $("#container img").css("width", containerw + "px");
    if (width > 1024) {
      var containerb = $("#container video").width();
      var containerm = (width - containerb) / 2;
      $("#container").css("width", containerb + "px");
      $("#container").css("left", containerm + "px");
    }
  } else {
    $("#container video").css("height", videoh + "px");
    $("#container img").css("height", imgh + "px");
    if (width > 1024) {
      var containerb = $("#container video").width();
      var containerm = (width - containerb) / 2;
      $("#container").css("width", containerb + "px");
      $("#container").css("left", containerm + "px");
    }
  }

  if (width < 1025) {
    var font3 = height / 11;
    $("#title, #hand1, #hand2").css("margin-top", font3 + "px");
  } else {
    /* niets */
  }
  if ($("#video1").height() - 1 > videoh) {
    $("#video1").css("border-radius", "0");
  } else {
    /* niets */
  }

  $(window).resize(function() {
    var height = $(window).height();
    var width = $(window).width();
    var logoh = height / 6;
    var font = height / 18;
    var font1 = font / 3;
    var font2 = font / 2;
    var containerw = width * 0.7;
    var containerh = height * 0.8;
    var res1 = 1938 / 1252;
    var res2 = containerw / containerh;
    var videoh = containerh * 0.87;
    var imgh = containerh * 0.129;
    var radius = height / 20;
    $("h1").css("font-size", font + "px");
    $("#title").css("top", font1 + "px");
    $("#menu p").css("font-size", font2 + "px");
    $("#hand1, #hand2").css("height", logoh + "px");
    $("#title, #hand1, #hand2").css("margin-top", font1 + "px");
    $("#container").css("max-width", containerw + "px");
    $("#container").css("max-height", containerh + "px");
    $("video").css("border-radius", radius + "px");
    if (res1 > res2) {
      $("#container video").css("width", containerw + "px");
      $("#container img").css("width", containerw + "px");
      if (width > 1024) {
        var containerb = $("#container video").width();
        var containerm = (width - containerb) / 2;
        $("#container").css("width", containerb + "px");
        $("#container").css("left", containerm + "px");
      }
    } else {
      $("#container video").css("height", videoh + "px");
      $("#container img").css("height", imgh + "px");
      if (width > 1024) {
        var containerb = $("#container video").width();
        var containerm = (width - containerb) / 2;
        $("#container").css("width", containerb + "px");
        $("#container").css("left", containerm + "px");
      }
    }

    if (width < 1025) {
      var font3 = height / 11;
      $("#title, #hand1, #hand2").css("margin-top", font3 + "px");
    } else {
      /* niets */
    }
    if ($("#video1").height() - 1 > videoh) {
      $("#video1").css("border-radius", "0");
    } else {
      /* niets */
    }

  });
});

$(window).bind('load', function() {
  var width = $(window).width();
  if (width > 1024) {
    var containerb = $("#container video").width();
    var containerm = (width - containerb) / 2;
    $("#container").css("width", containerb + "px");
    $("#container").css("left", containerm + "px");
  }

  $(window).resize(function() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width > 1024) {
      var containerb = $("#container video").width();
      var containerm = (width - containerb) / 2;
      $("#container").css("width", containerb + "px");
      $("#container").css("left", containerm + "px");
    }

  });
});
```

```css
Css

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}
h1 {
  color: #0070c0;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: italic;
}
font {
  color: #ed27b9;
}
#suite {
  position: absolute;
  width: 6.5%;
  right: 2.5%;
  bottom: 2.5%;
}
#suite img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
#menu {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("../beelden/postit.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 12%;
  left: 1%;
  bottom: 1%;
  transform: rotate(-7deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-7deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-7deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-7deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-7deg);
}
#menu p {
  position: relative;
  padding: 27% 20% 35% 20%;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  -moz-text-decoration-color: black;
  -webkit-text-decoration-color: black;
  -moz-text-decoration-color: black;
  text-decoration-color: black;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-family: comic sans ms;
  font-weight: normal;
}
#hand1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
#title {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
#hand2 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
#container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #menu {
    width: 13%;
  }
  #suite {
    right: 2%;
    bottom: 1%;
    width: 8%;
  }
  #container {
    left: 154px;
  }
}
```

```html
html

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Un accident cardiaque ? Rencontrez votre jumeau</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <img id="hand1" src="../beelden/hand1.png">
  <h1 id="title">Un accident cardiaque...<br><font>Je veux comprendre !</font></h1>
  <img id="hand2" src="../beelden/hand2.png">
  <div id="container">
    <video id="video1" frameborder="0" poster="../beelden/film2.png" preload="none" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen controls>
      <source src="../video/film2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="../video/film2.ogg" type="video/ogg">
          <source src="../video/film2.webm" type="video/webm">
            Your browser does not support the video tag
    </video>
    <img src="../beelden/reflectie2.png">
  </div>
  <a id="menu" href="menu.html">
    <p>
      Menu
      <br>Principal
    </p>
  </a>
  <a id="suite" href="comprendre2.html">
    <img src="../beelden/suite.png">
  </a>
</body>
```

Comment: indentation would help readability...

Comment: Indentation is done. Forgot to tidy it, sorry.

Comment: Have you tired flexbox? I don't think you should use `js` for this. IE11 fully supports flexbox http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: I have tried it, but it doesnt work every time I try. Or it could be that I do not use flexbox the right way. And flexbox is not fully supported by firefox, even though the charter saids is does, it gives errors in the firefox browser I use (v37).

Comment: Firefox fully supports it in its latest stable version. I don't know what errors you might get for a CSS property.. Are you using a polyfill? Check out http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/